# How does std::set determine whether to include a new insert?

Tags: c++, set

The answer seems obvious, but I have an example like this (simplified, not real code):

```
class A {
  double a;
  double b;
operator>(..) { return this->a < other.a; }
operator==(..) { return this->b == other.b; }
```

I find that if I insert a new entry into `std::set<A>` with a unique `b`, but the same `a` it does not get inserted, as though it is considered equal.

What is the explanation?

Comment: "_with a unique c_": There is no `c` in your code.

Comment: Why have you defined your `operator>` to do less-than comparison?

Comment: "simplified, not real" code is not very useful for finding bugs in your actual code.  A minimal example (no unnecessary code remains) that actually demonstrates the problem when run, with actual code is infinitely more useful.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that actually compiles and exhibits the behavior you are experiencing

Comment: Edited "c" mistake in question.  My > looks like < because I want the set sorted in reverse order.   The one answer I received answered the question, not sure why everyone is always so insistent on real code.  This was a general question about how sets work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the purpose of `std::set` or any ordered container two values are equivalent if neither is smaller than the other, with "smaller" referring to the result of `<` via `std::less` by default if no other comparator to replace it is specified. `==`, `!=`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` are not used in this determination.